# Setting stylesheet for one element

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a style for a web user control, I placed it in the form element in my masterpage. but the stylesheet of the webuser control affect all other elements that come in the content place holder.

Here is a picture of what happened:
[image]

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding:0;}

body {
    background: #333 url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat top left;
    font-family: Arial;
    color:white;
    font-size:12px;

}

form {
  background:#111; 
  width:300px;
  margin:30px auto;
  border-radius:0.4em;
  border:1px solid #191919;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}


.inset {
  padding:20px; 
  border-top:1px solid #19191a;
}

form h1 {
  font-size:18px;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 black;
  text-align:center;
  padding:15px 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position:relative;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width:100%;
  padding:8px 5px;
  background:linear-gradient(#1f2124, #27292c);
  border:1px solid #222;
  box-shadow:
    0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-radius:0.3em;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

label[for=remember]{
  color:white;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-top:5px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}


input[type=submit] {
  padding:5px 20px;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-radius:0.3em;
  background:#0184ff;
  color:white;
  float:right;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:13px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

input[type=text]:hover,
input[type=password]:hover,
label:hover ~ input[type=text],
label:hover ~ input[type=password] {
  background:#27292c;
}
```

Comment: add style sheet from code behind(using c# or vb.net) instead from presentation logic

Comment: Please identify which element you are referring, what you are trying to set on it, and what goes wrong with it (in terms of something that we can directly see). Also please remove tags other than “html” and “css” or explain how they are relevant to the question.

Comment: @vaibhav how can i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class or Id through html code to the specific control you want to override and write separate css for that like:

```
<form class="form-class"></form>

.form-class{
  background:#FFF; 
  width:500px;
  margin:30px auto;
  border-radius:0.4em;
  border:1px solid #191919;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Then check your output it is still showing the same result then you have add important to the required property like:

```
.form-class{
  background:#FFF !important; 
  width:500px !important;
  margin:30px auto;
  border-radius:0.4em;
  border:1px solid #191919;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

This will help you to override specific css on html controller.

Comment: i wrote it in this way:
<div id="login">
        <webUserControl:myControl runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" />   </div>
and then i added #login to every element
and its still not working

Comment: @user3100708: you just need to override by using important for specific change you want as I shown above, still it would not working then only try to use inline css.

Answer (score 0):

Use InLine CSS or else give ID or class to the element and Write its CSS in the same page.